# upload yarn application logs from emr cluster to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I know they can be uploaded to s3 in ~5 minute intervals with logpusher, but I would ideally like to get them within 30s-1min of step completion.

The logs I am looking for are the application logs for stdout

I can ssh to the master node and get these logs via:

`yarn logs -applicationId <<application_id>>`

Is there a way that I can either write a bootstrap script that restarts the logpusher service after a step has been completed, or a way to submit an emr step that will export the yarn logs to s3?

EDIT:

I ended up accomplishing this task by setting up an automatic follow-up job with boto3 utilizing AWS's script-runner jar, where I run a bash script that creates a text file from the yarn cli of a list of yarn application id's, downloads a python script from s3 I made to parse this text file and find the most recent applicationid, then pass that appID to the yarn cli to make a text file of that apps logs, then uploads them to s3 again. This reduces the wait time to ~15 seconds after a job completes.

Answer (score 0):

You need not specify anything. By default, EMR pushes application logs to s3 location specified in `Log Uri`. Just look under `containers` in the `Log Uri` location.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Even though what you said is true, it only uploads those logs to s3 every ~5 minutes. I was trying to lower the wait period.